# Create clickable row of a js populated table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've created a table using an AJAX request to the database of items in our  inventory displaying a picture/part name/price/stock remaining. When the table displays I would like to be able to click on any part of one of the rows and have it link to the item page associated with that item but it won't work.

I've tried the `on.click` with a static table written right into the html and it worked fine. Also if I direct the on.click script to just the table id instead of the table id and tr i can make the entire table clickable to the first row's href. So it appears that since the tr doesn't really exist in the html the javascript won't find it. Is there a way to get the script to recognize each 's href attribute?

HTML CODE + on.click script:

```
<html>    
        <body>
            <table id="ctable">
                <tbody id="tbody1" class="tbody1">
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <script>
                $('#ctable tr').click(function() {
                    var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
                    if(href) {
                        window.location = href;
                    }
                });
            </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

.JS File CODE that creates table from .php file/mysql database

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        $.post('test.php', function(data) {
            $("#tbody1").empty();

            $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (index, value){
                var eachrow = "<tr>" +
                "<td class=\"image\">" + '<img src="images/thumbs/' + 
                value.image + '">' + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + '<a href="' + value.link + '">' + value.part + " 
                </td>" +
                "<td>" + value.price + "</td>"
                "<td>" + value.stock + "</td>"
                "</tr>";
                $('#tbody1').append(eachrow);
            });
        });
    }, false);
```

Comment: Try doing $('#ctable tr').on('click', function()..... as you are rendering the table data via ajax, and the existing click method assumes that you are clicking on elements already loaded into the DOM at runtime.

Comment: You need event delegation instead of binding. Change $('#ctable tr').click(function() { ===> $(document).on('click' ,' #ctable tr ' , (function() {. You need to do so for event handler to listen to any change in the DOM and target the respective element.

Comment: $("#ctable").on('click' ,'tr' , (function() {...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are dynamically adding rows, you need to either restructure your click event to listen from the context of the parent as in:

```
$("#tbody1").on("click", "tr", function(e) {

});
```

Assuming `#tbody1` is a good place to start since you probably don't want the header row to be clickable.  Or, every time you dynamically add rows, since the code is rebuilding the table, you can reattach the click event handlers:

```
      $("#tbody1").empty();

        $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (index, value){
            var eachrow = "..
            $('#tbody1').append(eachrow);
        });

        // or .on("click", function() { })
        $("#tbody1 tr").click(function() { });
```

If you attach click handler via on, it would be good to then do an off as in:

```
$("#tbody1").off("click", "tr");
```

To remove the existing click handlers.

Comment: Listening from the view of the parent makes total sense. Works great. Thank you!